# Cross Platform GUI Library for Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, delphi, user-interface

Does anyone have recommendations on a cross platform GUI Library for Ruby. I have looked at https://github.com/brixen/wxruby and it seems like its dead (the last code push is more than 2 years ago), but I need something on similar lines. The goal is to build a native app for Windows/OS X and Linux. My other option currently is to learn pascal and buy Delphi :(

Comment: Delphi is not an option for Linux. Perhaps in the future Delphi will be supported on Linux. Windows and OSX yes, but not Linux. And the OSX offering is based on FireMonkey which is currently of rather low quality. Delphi/VCL is still great on Windows though.

Comment: Delphi currently doesn't support Linux, but Lazarus does.

Comment: @Torbins Well, really it's FPC that supports Linux. FPC is the compiler.

Comment: @David Heffernan both FPC and Lazarus support Linux: http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/page,7.html

Comment: @Torbins Yes I know that. It's just that lots of people confuse Lazarus and FPC.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into [qtruby](http://rubyforge.org/projects/korundum/). It's actively developed, works on Windows, OSX and Linux and there even is [an (old) ebook about it](http://pragprog.com/book/ctrubyqt/rapid-gui-development-with-qtruby).

Answer (score 0):

I will try:

http://shoesrb.com/